# Operator [&] in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cygwin

I have a code and when I'm building it in cygwin enviroment I get errors related to `[&]` What does [&] mean? How do I solve this or what do I replace it with to make it work?

Code:

```
this->func =[&]()
{ in here call other functions }
```

Comment: What version of g++ are you trying to use ?

Comment: Not sure why it's downvoted. If you mistake `[&]` for an operator, googling won't help you.

Comment: I formatted your question a little, but it still qualifies as "not a real question" by SO criteria. Try to fix it by giving a bit more context and real code, exact error messages, compiler version, etc...

Comment: Just know is gcc version 3.4.4

Comment: The code is not mine and it's first time i use the cygwin in windows 7 64 bits to build a project in Android...and i stuck here...

Comment: That compiler is extremely outdated, [it will have its 8th birthday in a few days](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/). It's very unlikely that it could compile the project, even if you resolve this issue. There will be lots of other C++11 features used in the code, and that compiler is not fit to compile them.

Comment: I agree and had checked it too ... I will try to solve then. Thanks very much.

Comment: cygwin has much newer versions of g++ - check the [cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[&]{ /*function calls*/ }`

This is a C++11 **lambda expression**, which creates a function object (closure), that calls other functions. The `[&]` is the capture of the lambda expression, meaning the closure may use every variable outside the lambda expression by reference. You might want to read a current C++11 book or at least an article about lambdas.

To fix your problem, try to pass `-std=c++0x` as compiler argument, If that does not work, either upgrade to a current compiler (yours seems to be older than ~2 years), or create a function object manually. How to do that will be trivial once you understood lambdas. However, if the code you are trying to compile uses lambdas, that might not be the only C++11 feature, so I strongly recommend the compiler upgrade.

Comment: that's exactly the error and warming saying " warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]"...i will try upgrade permanently!

Comment: What better site would you recommend to upgrade?

Comment: That's curious that gcc 3.4.4 would tell you about command line parameters introduced in gcc 4.7.

Answer (score 4):

The `[capture-list](arguments){function-body}` syntax is a C++11 lambda. You need a fairly recent compiler, and possibly pass an additional compiler flag.